# Why is no ValueError raised?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-3.11

I am currently working on my assignment for python class and need some help. I wrote the following function:

```
def get_funcs(funcs: dict, file_name: str, table_name: str) -> None:
    '''
    Read the given *.csv file, store the data inside the database and store the functions in a dict
    
    Args:
        functions dict: Dictionary to store the functions object
        file_name str: The file name of the csv-file with file extension
        table_name str: The name of the SQL table
    '''    
    
    global update_database

    try:
        if file_name == "test.csv" or file_name == "test":
            raise ValueError("The function for the test data is not neccessary.")
        elif file_name != "train.csv" and file_name != "train" and file_name != "ideal.csv" and file_name != "ideal":
            raise ValueError("Given a completly wrong / empty file or a directorys.")
        
        # store the complete path to the file in a variable
        complete_path = os.path.join(dataset_dir, file_name)
        # check file to be correct
        file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_name)[1]
        if file_extension == "":
            print_log(MessageType.Warn, "get_funcs", "Missing file extension. Added "".csv"" automatically!")
            complete_path += ".csv"        
        if not os.path.exists(complete_path):
            raise FileNotFoundError()
        
        # read csv file and store it in a data frame
        data = pd.read_csv(complete_path, sep=",")
        print_log(MessageType.Info, "get_funcs", "Successfully read \"" + file_name + "\"!")
    except PermissionError as error:
        print_log(MessageType.Error, "get_funcs", "Cannot open the given csv file!")
        return
    except Exception as error:
        print_log(MessageType.Error, "get_funcs", error)
        return
```

Part of the task is to write unit tests. So I wrote the following:

```
import main
import unittest

class UnitTestPythonTask(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_check_test_function(self):
        '''
        Checks the file validation of the given .csv files
        '''
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, main.get_funcs({}, "test.csv", "TestFunction"))
```

The test fails because no ValueError is raised. If I set a breakpoint and watch the single steps, I can see, that the ValueError is raised and got logged (`print_log`).

I tried to set the `raise ValueError("Given a completly wrong / empty file or a directorys.")` outside of the try... except... Block, with no luck. After the test succeeded when I'm checking if an exception is raised, I added an addtionall except for the ValueError. Also with no luck.

Can anybody tell me, why the test fails althoug the ValueError is raised?

Comment: Because you’re catching it yourself with `except Exception as error`

Comment: Yeah, I also assumed that. But as I described, it tried to set it outside of a try catch block, so it won't be catched. Had no luck with this..

Comment: You should test for the `print_log` call, not for the exception that is an implementation detail that doesn't get propagated outside of your function.

Comment: But how can I then determine, why `print_log` was called?

Comment: Test the log message, that is what the user of the function gets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a broad exception in your function`except Exception as error:`  that is capturing any errors that are raised and return `None` from the function after calling `print_log`. And that is why you are not seeing any exceptions raised in your tests.

In you question you haven't said what `print_log` is so I've implemented a place holder that assumes you are printing to `stdout`. The tests should then look for what is output on `stdout`. e.g.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import io
import unittest.mock
import main


class UnitTestPythonTask(unittest.TestCase):
    @unittest.mock.patch("sys.stdout", new_callable=io.StringIO)
    @unittest.mock.patch(
        "main.get_log_time", unittest.mock.MagicMock(return_value=datetime(1972, 1, 1))
    )
    def test_check_test_function(self, mock_stdout):
        """
        Checks the file validation for test.csv file
        """
        expected_output = ("MessageType.Error "
                           "- 1972-01-01 00:00:00 - get_funcs "
                           "- The function for the test data is not necessary.\n")
        main.get_funcs(funcs={}, file_name="test.csv", table_name="TestFunction")
        self.assertEqual(mock_stdout.getvalue(), expected_output)

    @unittest.mock.patch("sys.stdout", new_callable=io.StringIO)
    @unittest.mock.patch(
        "main.get_log_time", unittest.mock.MagicMock(return_value=datetime(1972, 1, 1))
    )
    def test_check_wrong_file(self, mock_stdout):
        """
        Checks the file validation for a bad .csv file
        """
        expected_output = ("MessageType.Error "
                           "- 1972-01-01 00:00:00 - get_funcs "
                           "- Given a completly wrong / empty file or a directory.\n")
        main.get_funcs(funcs={}, file_name="bad_file.csv", table_name="TestFunction")
        self.assertEqual(mock_stdout.getvalue(), expected_output)
```

For reference, this is what my `main.py` contained:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from enum import Enum, auto
import os

dataset_dir = "/tmp"


class MessageType(Enum):
    Warn = auto()
    Error = auto()


def get_log_time():
    return datetime.now()


def print_log(msg_type, func, msg):
    print(f"{msg_type} - {get_log_time()} - {func} - {msg}")


def get_funcs(funcs: dict, file_name: str, table_name: str) -> None:
    """
    Read the given *.csv file, store the data inside the database and store the functions in a dict

    Args:
        functions dict: Dictionary to store the functions object
        file_name str: The file name of the csv-file with file extension
        table_name str: The name of the SQL table
    """
    global update_database

    try:
        if file_name == "test.csv" or file_name == "test":
            raise ValueError("The function for the test data is not necessary.")
        elif (
            file_name != "train.csv"
            and file_name != "train"
            and file_name != "ideal.csv"
            and file_name != "ideal"
        ):
            raise ValueError("Given a completly wrong / empty file or a directorys.")

        # store the complete path to the file in a variable
        complete_path = os.path.join(dataset_dir, file_name)
        # check file to be correct
        file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_name)[1]
        if file_extension == "":
            print_log(
                MessageType.Warn,
                "get_funcs",
                "Missing file extension. Added " ".csv" " automatically!",
            )
            complete_path += ".csv"
        if not os.path.exists(complete_path):
            raise FileNotFoundError()

        # read csv file and store it in a data frame
        data = pd.read_csv(complete_path, sep=",")
        print_log(
            MessageType.Info, "get_funcs", 'Successfully read "' + file_name + '"!'
        )
    except PermissionError as error:
        print_log(MessageType.Error, "get_funcs", "Cannot open the given csv file!")
        return
    except Exception as error:
        print_log(MessageType.Error, "get_funcs", error)
        return
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Basically your right, that I am printing a `stdout`, but this includes a timestamp. It seems like, that `mock_stdout.getvalue()[20:]` won't remove the timestamp. Even not, if I'm converting it to a string... Do you know why?

Comment: That command should have worked although it is difficult to know if you are not showing your code. You could update your question with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can run it. I've updated the answer to mock the datetime given in the logging so the full output can be tested.

Comment: The `print_log` function prints a color log message to the console: `get_log_time() + " " + method + " [" + msg_type.name + "]: " + str(msg)`. The color depends on the `msg_type`, which is an enum. Your updated code rasies an error: `AssertionError: '\x1b[31m01/01/1900 00:00:00 get_funcs [Er[65 chars]7m\n' != '1900-01-01 00:00:00 get_funcs [Error]: Gi[46 chars]ory.'`

Comment: I found out, that the problem was the formatting. I'm using the colorama package for coloring the output. This caused that the strings starts with some bytes. Thanks for your help :D